# How to prevent Django's prefetch_related from caching a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have the following queryset function for an **Argument** model:

```
class ArgumentQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def prefetch_related_objects(self):
        from views.models import View

        return self.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'argument_reactions',
                queryset=View.objects.filter(type=ViewType.ARGUMENT_REACTION.name,
                                             reaction_type=ReactionType.ENDORSE.name),
                to_attr='endorsement_reactions'
            ),
            Prefetch(
                'argument_reactions',
                queryset=View.objects.filter(type=ViewType.ARGUMENT_REACTION.name,
                                             reaction_type=ReactionType.DISAGREE.name),
                to_attr='disagreement_reactions'
            ),
        )
```

As you can see I'm trying to prefetch the same relation using different querysets and I'm also using the **to_attr** parameter of the **Prefetch** object. The problem is the second prefetch is not working properly, the **disagreement_reactions** list is empty. But it works if I remove the first prefetch. I believe the first queryset, i.e., **View.objects** is being cached somehow. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

According to Django documentation, you can pass:

```
queryset.prefetch_related(None)
```

As it will clear any prefetch_related behavior

Here is the reference for it [Click Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: Does that mean I add another prefetch_related? I mean after: queryset.prefetch_related(None).